# How can I parse environment variables in a string?

Tags: plugin-development, environmentvariables

I have a string in my plugin that contains environment variables. How can I parse them the same way Craft does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
craft()->config->parseEnvironmentString($string)
```